# Select Method returns strings like @{Name=

Tags: powershell

I'd like to select items from the pipeline using "select" but it returns raw data like: `@{Name=MyMachine}`

This will not be helpful if, say I want to reboot `@{Name=MyMachine}` because there is not machine named `@{Name=MyMachine}`

There's a "MyMachine" but the script does not return just the name.

How do you strip out the "`@{Name="}`" when selecting individual objects?

Answer (score 5):

Use the -ExpandProperty parameter of Select-Object:

```
 $someobjects | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is echoing the property in a loop:

```
$something | % { $_.Name }
```