# How to get rid of @{name =xyz} and only use xyz?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script in which I first Import a csv and the use the content of this csv. When using it, it comes in this form: `@{name =xyz}`

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\CLEAN-UP.csv" -Delimiter ";"

Foreach ($item In $csv) {
    Write-Output $item
    $path = "C:\Users\$item\Downloads"
    Write-Output $path

}
```

Path comes like this:
`C:\Users@{name =xyz}\Downloads`

CSV looks like this:

| name |
| --- |
| xyz |
| zyx |

**How can I now modify my script so in the path it's only xyz?**

I tried all the thing on this page but nothing worked for me: [Select Method returns strings like @{Name=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243736/select-method-returns-strings-like-name)

Comment: `$path = "C:\Users\$($item.name)\Downloads"` or `foreach ($item in $csv.name) {..`

Comment: Looks like the header name is `name<space>`, so you'd need `foreach ($item in $csv.'name ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either filter the input so it no longer includes the header information, or alternatively when referencing the input value, specify explicitly that you want the "Name" value. There are a few ways to do that (there may be others).

Handle it within the initial `Import-Csv` step

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\CLEAN-UP.csv" -Delimiter ";" | select -ExpandProperty Name
Foreach ($item In $csv) {
    Write-Output $item
    $path = "C:\Users\$item\Downloads"
    Write-Output $path
}
```

Handle it within the `Foreach` step

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\CLEAN-UP.csv" -Delimiter ";" 
Foreach ($item In $csv.name) {
    Write-Output $item
    $path = "C:\Users\$item\Downloads"
    Write-Output $path
}
```

Individually reference the value as and when needed (Most useful when you're referencing multiple columns from an imported CSV, and therefore don't want to filter it earlier)

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\CLEAN-UP.csv" -Delimiter ";"
Foreach ($item In $csv) {
    Write-Output $item.name
    $path = "C:\Users\$($item.name)\Downloads"
    Write-Output $path
}
```